# Django template: 2 for loops with same iterable seems to be interfering with each other

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

So I have 2 for loops in an HTML template, back to back that are both using the same iterable like so:

```
{% for counter in iSM %}
    #some code here
{% empty %}
    <p>There's a missing tab here.</p>
{% endfor %}

{% for iteration in iSM %}
    #some code here
    {% endif %}
{% empty %}
    <p>There's a missing context here.</p>
{% endfor %}
```

The issue I have with this is it seems that the counter doesn't reset. The first for loop will operate as normal, no problem. The second for loop will trigger the empty. Switching the order of these for loops will work for whatever loop is on top.

How do I go around having both loops return all elements of the view the same?

**EDIT:** Here's the model:

```
class iSM(models.Model):
    iSM_title = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    iSM_alias = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

Here's the view:

```
view_iSM_title = iSM.objects.values_list('iSM_title', flat=True)
view_iSM_alias = iSM.objects.values_list('iSM_alias', flat=True)

iSM_zip = zip(view_iSM_title, view_iSM_alias)
```

Comment: Is your iterable a generator or other iterator that can be iterated only once?

Comment: Please show the view; what exactly is iSM?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I added the model and views for context. Maybe it also helps to say that there are 4 stored items with that model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 3, zip returns a generator; those can only be iterated once. You should call `list()` on it before passing it to the template.

Comment: Ah, didn't know that. Thanks!